# Supplying Authorization Header

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3, nuxt-auth

How to supply the `"Authorization: Bearer xxxxx"` header in `Vueform`?

That is, how to `extend` this line to include the `authorization header`?

```
<Vueform endpoint="https://xxxxx.xx/xxxxx" method="post">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vueform uses axios to send requests.  All configuration options in the [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) can be applied in `vueform.config.js`, including headers:

```js
// vueform.config.js

export default {
  axios: {
    headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` }
  },
  // ...
}
```

You can also provide an existing pre-configured axios instance if you have one, as seen in the [Vueform documentation](https://vueform.com/reference/configuration#axios)

```js
// vueform.config.js
import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.headers.common = { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}` }

export default {
  axios,
  // ...
}
```